# order all row according to contents of a row

Tags: python

I have a an excel file of data with 3 columns. I copied the data onto a text pad to have .txt (tab-delimited) instead of .xls for easy data parsing. I will like to sort all rows according to the first numeric number of a numeric interval and the word "complement" if they appear before the numeric interval. My data is below ( a few of the rows have empty 3rd column rows 1,2,3,5, 7, 8,9, 15):

```
81228..81500    Gene 22 
81500..81856    Gene 17 
complement(82256..84292)    Gene 75 
84307..85275    Gene 23  2.7.4.8
complement(97435..98067)    Gene 91 
complement(85325..86527)    Gene 34 3.5.1.32
86756..87025    Gene 36 
complement(92373..93341)    Gene 45 
88076..90292    Gene 34 
complement(90289..92415)    Gene 89  3.6.1.-
93492..94931    Gene 92  2.2.1.1
complement(97087..97347)    Gene 12  2.7.7.6
complement(94928..97060)    Gene 58  2.5.6.3, 3.1.8.2
79951..81162    Gene 3   1.7.1.2
complement(87022..87837)    Gene 77
10..1008    Gene 500    
100059..100178  Gene 501    
100470..104660  Gene 502     6.3.5.5
100715..100861  Gene 503    
101721..103604  Gene 504    
101782..103698  Gene 505     1.1.1.49
1018..1137  Gene 506    
10230..11636    Gene 507     6.3.1.2
102328..104049  Gene 508    
10321..12651    Gene 509     2.3.1.16, 2.3.1.9
103256..104290  Gene 510    
103607..104647  Gene 511    
103658..104662  Gene 512     4.1.3.16, 4.1.2.14
103732..106095  Gene 513    
104045..106027  Gene 514    
104057..104305  Gene 515    
10416..14087    Gene 516    
104237..105262  Gene 517     3.1.11.2
```

My expected output:

```
79951..81162    Gene 3   1.7.1.2
81228..81500    Gene 22 
81500..81856    Gene 17 
84307..85275    Gene 23  2.7.4.8
86756..87025    Gene 36 
88076..90292    Gene 34 
93492..94931    Gene 92  2.2.1.1
complement(82256..84292)    Gene 75 
complement(85325..86527)    Gene 34 3.5.1.32
complement(87022..87837)    Gene 77 
complement(90289..92415)    Gene 89  3.6.1.-
complement(92373..93341)    Gene 45 
complement(94928..97060)    Gene 58  2.5.6.3, 3.1.8.2
complement(97087..97347)    Gene 12  2.7.7.6
complement(97435..98067)    Gene 91
```

My try using python is as follows:

```
import re
import sys
#import csv


pattern = '^complement\(\d+\.{2}\d+\)$'

#pattern = '^complement'

regexp = re.compile(pattern)

input_file = open('infile.txt', 'r')

output_file = open('outfile.txt','w')

for line in input_file:
    item = line[0]
    match = regexp.search(item)
    if match:
              output_file.writerow([line[0],\t,line1[1],\t, line[2]])
      #output_file.writerow(line[0])

#del line[0], line[1], line[2], item

del output_file
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Can someone please help!

Comment: Your current code won't run. Please provide a [minimal example](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the error. Also, you can export from *.xls to e.g. *.csv, which is smarter than copying and pasting.

Comment: `output_file = open('outfile.txt','w'` missing `)`....

Comment: Can there be overlapping intervals?

Comment: Use natural sort to sort on the magnitude of numbers. See my edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works:

```
txt='''\
81228..81500    Gene 22 
81500..81856    Gene 17 
complement(82256..84292)    Gene 75 
84307..85275    Gene 23  2.7.4.8
complement(97435..98067)    Gene 91 
complement(85325..86527)    Gene 34 3.5.1.32
86756..87025    Gene 36 
complement(92373..93341)    Gene 45 
88076..90292    Gene 34 
complement(90289..92415)    Gene 89  3.6.1.-
93492..94931    Gene 92  2.2.1.1
complement(97087..97347)    Gene 12  2.7.7.6
complement(94928..97060)    Gene 58  2.5.6.3, 3.1.8.2
79951..81162    Gene 3   1.7.1.2
complement(87022..87837)    Gene 77 '''

import re

lines=txt.splitlines()

print('\n'.join(sorted(lines, key=lambda s: re.search(r'^((?:\d+)|(?:complement\(\d+))', s).group(1))))
```

Or, if it is really tab separated, you can loose the regex and do:

```
txt='''\
81228..81500\tGene 22 
81500..81856\tGene 17 
complement(82256..84292)\tGene 75 
84307..85275\tGene 23\t2.7.4.8
complement(97435..98067)\tGene 91 
complement(85325..86527)\tGene 34\t3.5.1.32
86756..87025\tGene 36 
complement(92373..93341)\tGene 45 
88076..90292\tGene 34 
complement(90289..92415)\tGene 89\t3.6.1.-
93492..94931\tGene 92\t2.2.1.1
complement(97087..97347)\tGene 12\t2.7.7.6
complement(94928..97060)\tGene 58\t2.5.6.3, 3.1.8.2
79951..81162\tGene 3\t1.7.1.2
complement(87022..87837)\tGene 77 '''

lines=txt.splitlines()
print('\n'.join(sorted(lines, key=lambda s: s.split('\t',1)[0])))
```

But since you are sorting on the first element, you do not NEED to split it at all:

```
print('\n'.join(sorted(lines)))
```

Any case above, prints:

```
79951..81162    Gene 3   1.7.1.2
81228..81500    Gene 22 
81500..81856    Gene 17 
84307..85275    Gene 23  2.7.4.8
86756..87025    Gene 36 
88076..90292    Gene 34 
93492..94931    Gene 92  2.2.1.1
complement(82256..84292)    Gene 75 
complement(85325..86527)    Gene 34 3.5.1.32
complement(87022..87837)    Gene 77 
complement(90289..92415)    Gene 89  3.6.1.-
complement(92373..93341)    Gene 45 
complement(94928..97060)    Gene 58  2.5.6.3, 3.1.8.2
complement(97087..97347)    Gene 12  2.7.7.6
complement(97435..98067)    Gene 91
```

---

One of your comments states that you want the magnitude of the number to count rather than just lexicographic order.

You can use [natural sort order](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/) to achieve this:

```
import re

data='''\
81728..81500    Gene 22 
81500..81856    Gene 17 
complement(82256..84292)    Gene 75 
812..815    Gene 3 num
complement(822..842)    Gene compliment 3 num75  
811..815    Gene 3 num
'''

def alpha_num_sort(li): 
    def convert(s):
        return int(s) if s.isdigit() else s

    def key_func(key):
        return tuple(convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key))

    return sorted(li, key = key_func)

print '\n'.join(alpha_num_sort(data.splitlines()))
```

Prints:

```
811..815    Gene 3 num
812..815    Gene 3 num
81500..81856    Gene 17 
81728..81500    Gene 22 
complement(822..842)    Gene compliment 3 num75  
complement(82256..84292)    Gene 75
```

Comment: Thanks. It works fine but unable to write the dataproperly with the following: out = open('outfile.csv', 'w')
out.write(alpha_num_sort(data.splitlines())). How can I write this better?

Comment: `.splitlines()` and `alpha_num_sort(li)` produces a list. You need to write a string. Do something like `for line in alpha_num_sort(data.splitlines()): out.write(line)` You may need to add a `\n`

Comment: I was able to write to file this way:   for line in alpha_num_sort(data.splitlines()):      
 out.write("%s\n" % line). Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

this should work fine, no need to create `txt` file. just import `csv`:

```
In [23]: reader = csv.reader(open('tets.xls','rb'),delimiter='\t')

In [24]: f = list(reader)

In [25]: f #original file
Out[25]: 
[['81228..81500', 'Gene', '22 '],
 ['81500..81856', 'Gene', '17 '],
 ['complement(82256..84292)', 'Gene', '75 '],
 ['84307..85275', 'Genne', '23', '2.7.4.8'],
 ['complement(97435..98067)', 'Gene', '91 '],
 ['complement(85325..86527)', 'Gene', '34', '3.5.1.32'],
 ['86756..87025', 'Gene', '36 '],
 ['complement(92373..93341)', 'Gene', '45 '],
 ['88076..90292', 'Gene', '34 '],
 ['complement(90289..92415)', 'Gene 89', '3.6.1.-'],
 ['93492..94931', 'Genne', '92', '2.2.1.1'],
 ['complement(97087..97347)', 'Gene', '12', '2.7.7.6'],
 ['complement(94928..97060)', 'Gene', '58', '2.5.6.3, 3.1.8.2'],
 ['79951..81162', 'Gene', '3', '1.7.1.2'],
 ['complement(87022..87837)', 'Gene', '77 ']]

In [26]: f.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

In [27]: f #after sorting
Out[27]: 
[['79951..81162', 'Gene', '3', '1.7.1.2'],
 ['81228..81500', 'Gene', '22 '],
 ['81500..81856', 'Gene', '17 '],
 ['84307..85275', 'Genne', '23', '2.7.4.8'],
 ['86756..87025', 'Gene', '36 '],
 ['88076..90292', 'Gene', '34 '],
 ['93492..94931', 'Genne', '92', '2.2.1.1'],
 ['complement(82256..84292)', 'Gene', '75 '],
 ['complement(85325..86527)', 'Gene', '34', '3.5.1.32'],
 ['complement(87022..87837)', 'Gene', '77 '],
 ['complement(90289..92415)', 'Gene 89', '3.6.1.-'],
 ['complement(92373..93341)', 'Gene', '45 '],
 ['complement(94928..97060)', 'Gene', '58', '2.5.6.3, 3.1.8.2'],
 ['complement(97087..97347)', 'Gene', '12', '2.7.7.
```

Answer (score 1):

My two-cents:

```
import csv
# get a list of lines in the file
with open('in.txt') as in_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter = '\t')
    lines = [line for line in reader]

lines.sort()
# generator to produce the desired output
lines = ('\n'.join(('\t'.join(line) for line in lines)))

with open('out.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write(lines)
```

Use a key function to extract the relevant sort parameters - replace `lines.sort()` above with:

```
def key_func(line):
    '''extract sorting parameters

    line --> list
    returns tuple
    '''
    key = line[0]
    complement = 'complement' in key
    # extract the interval
    key = key[key.find('(') + 1 : key.find(')')]
    # turn the interval into a 2 integer list
    key = map(int, key.split('..'))
    # return a tuple to sort on
    return complement, key


lines.sort(key = key_func)
```

`key_func` should return a tuple of values (in order of importance) that you want the data sorted on.  If your actual data matches your posted data exactly this will sort to your requirements.  If your actual does not exactly match your posted data, you will need to modify `key_func`.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found the solutions useful. But there was something that my data did not include - I did not include rows where the number of digits are less than 5 (first nuber in the numerical interval). For example, as part of my current output, I have rows sorted in this order: 101782..103698, 1018..1137, 10230..11636, 10321..12651, 103256..104290, 103607..104647,103658..104662. Is there any way of taking care of this situation as I would expect that 1018..1137 should come before the others. Thanks.

Comment: ```sort()```appears to handle that.  Did you try it?

Comment: Unfortunately, sort() did not handle it 100%.

Comment: Add some of the problem data to the example in your question. I tried 101..113, 1018..1137 and a couple of others and it worked.

Comment: Thanks. part of problem data now added to the example.

Comment: Can there be overlapping intervals?

Comment: Overlapping intervals are possible, but I have not come across any yet.

Comment: See the edit using a key function - for overlapping intervals with the same start value, the sort order will be the same as the original data.

Comment: Many thanks for your help wwii. The sorting is fine now, except the rows with complement are now sorted in-between the others, but I actually wanted the complement rows to come last as in the output example above. Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm, when I run this on your data the lines starting with `complement` are sorted to the bottom.  Put a ```print``` statement in the ```if key.startswith('complement'):``` suite and see if that part is executing.  Take a look at the edit, I refactored a bit to better account for overlapping intervals.

Comment: Tried the edited, but returned "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '81500    Gene 22 '" print statement not executing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55785/discussion-between-wwii-and-user27976).

Comment: Many thanks for your help wwii. I was able to use dawg's solution above for the problem. I really appreciate your time efforts.